# pyside parent of multiple uis gets destroyed if one ui closes

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qmessagebox

When I use the same parent QWidget for multiple UIs all UIs close, when one UI is closed by the user. Is there a good reason for that and a solution to keep the other UIs open, when they have the same parent?

Setting "setQuitOnLastWindowClosed" to false keeps the other UIs open, but of course I want to close QApplication, when the last window is closed, so that no solution for me.

Here is a quick example. When you close one messagebox, the second messagebox is closed, too, but I want it to stay open.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

class pCore():
    def __init__(self):
        self.msgParent = QWidget()
        self.msg1 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, "title", "test1", parent=self.msgParent)
        self.msg1.setModal(False)
        self.msg1.show()

        self.msg2 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, "title", "test2", parent=self.msgParent)
        self.msg2.setModal(False)
        self.msg2.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #qapp.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    pc = pCore()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec_())
```

Comment: That may be a misuse of QMessageboxes. Do you really need them? And why don't you show the msgParent QWidget?